How can I set the cellspace and vertical alignment for a row in a table?
I am creating a table with 2 rows as below, but I am not able to set the vertical cellspace for the second row:
\begin{tabular}{ | C{1.8cm} | C{1.8cm} | C{1.8cm} | C{1.8cm} | C{1.8cm} | } \hline
\( x \) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ \hline
P\( (X = x) \) & \( p\) & \( p\) & \( p \) & \( \dfrac{1}{2}p\) \\ \hline
\end{tabular}


How should I fix it? Thank you.

The minimum height is \arraystretch\ht\strutbox, but if something is larger, it increases (just like normal text).

Welcome to TeX.SX! You may try the cellspace package

With {NiceTabular} of nicematrix, which is similar to the environment {tabular} provided by the package array, you have a key cell-space-limits which sets the minimal space above and below the contents of the cells of the row.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{w{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily % optional -- switch to sans-serif text font

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{5}{C{1.8cm}}}[cell-space-limits=3pt,hvlines] 
\( x \) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
P\( (X = x) \) & \( p\) & \( p\) & \( p \) & \( \dfrac{1}{2}p\) \\ 
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}


nicematrix is compatible with booktabs:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{w{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\sffamily % optional -- switch to sans-serif text font

\begin{NiceTabular}{*{5}{C{1.8cm}}}[cell-space-limits=3pt] 
\toprule
\( x \) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\midrule
P\( (X = x) \) & \( p\) & \( p\) & \( p \) & \( \dfrac{1}{2}p\) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}



One way to solve the problem would be to cease using \hline instructions and, instead, start using the following line-drawing macros of the booktabs package: \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule. Note that using these macros will require you to no longer use vertical rules in a table. But, trust me, these vertical rules won't be missed. And, as the resulting table will have a much more open and inviting "look", you'll be raising the odds that your readers will pause and actually take in and absorb the information contained in the table.
The following screenshot and associated code contrasts the looks of tables that use \hline or a combination of \toprule, \midrule, and \bottomrule.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}   % for \dfrac macro
\usepackage{booktabs}  % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{array} % for \newcolumntype macro
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{wc{#1}} % ? is this definition ok?

\begin{document}
\sffamily % optional -- switch to sans-serif text font

\begin{tabular}{ | *{5}{C{1.8cm}|} } 
\hline
\( x \) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\hline
P\( (X = x) \) & \( p\) & \( p\) & \( p \) & \( \dfrac{1}{2}p\) \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{ *{5}{C{1.8cm}} } % note: no instances of "|"
\toprule
\( x \) & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\midrule
P\( (X = x) \) & \( p\) & \( p\) & \( p \) & \( \dfrac{1}{2}p\) \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


Very simple with tabularray:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
colspec={*{5}{Q[c,1.8cm]}},
hlines,
vlines,
columns={mode=math}
} 
x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\text{P}(X = x) & p & p & p & \dfrac{1}{2}p \\ 
\end{tblr}

\bigskip
Or, with \texttt{booktabs}:
\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{
colspec={*{5}{Q[c,1.8cm]}},
columns={mode=math}
} 
\toprule
x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 
\midrule
\text{P}(X = x) & p & p & p & \dfrac{1}{2}p \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{document}


